# Is a product of a Hurwitz matrix and a diagonal positive definite matrix always Hurwitz?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, hurwitz-matrices

If I multiply a Hurwitz matrix (real part of eigenvalues are negative) with a diagonal positive definite matrix, does the product still remain as Hurwitz matrix?

Comment: What is your definition of a Hurwitz matrix?

Comment: A matrix is said to be Hurwitz iff its eigenvalues have a strictly negative real part.

Answer (score 4):

How about
$$A=\pmatrix{1&1\\-4&-3}$$
and
$$B=\pmatrix{4&0\\0&1}.$$
Then $A$ has repeated eigenvalues $-1$ so is Hurwitz, but $BA$
has positive trace so isn't.